# "Help us grow this site" improvements

Tags: discussion, beta-progress

I was clicking in the "Help us Grow this Site" box on the Pro Webmasters beta site, and there's a couple things that caught my notice.

First off, when focusing on the various icons, the layout shifts in a nasty way (FF 3.6.6):

[image]

Secondly, I question the choice of text for the pre-populated facebook link description:

> Pro Web Masters is a collaboratively
>   edited question and answer site for
>   professional web masters. It's 100%
>   free, no registration required.

"100% free" for me is a mental trigger for suspicious or misleading behavior on the web.  I would just say "It's free to participate" or something along those lines.

IMHO, I would also argue that "webmasters" and "web masters" have entirely different contexts, and it should say "webmasters" in both cases.

Comment: For me, "Free to participate" raises red flags, because I think to myself "Ahuh, what's not free then? What's the catch? Are you going to spam me?"

Comment: And "100% free" doesn't conjure up images of limited trial downloads, browser toolbars and spam sites?  It was just a suggestion... how about "Come and join us"?  "Everyone welcome!"?

Comment: Tim, I am running FF 3.6.8 and I do not have the issue.  Could be a version thing or something more specific to your computer?

Comment: too bad it's not "web developer".. but then you need to be able to do both the programming *and* the design..